# assign value of static array in dynamic function in php

Tags: php, arrays, static

I have a little problem.
I attempt to assign a value taken from a static array 
to a local variable in a dynamic function. 
As soon as I know... this is not a problem in other 
languages...

Am I doing something wrong?

the code i am using:

```
<?php
class SampleClass {
    private static st_ar = array(1 => '1', 2 => '2');

    private function work() {
        lv = st_ar[1]; //gives an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' 
        //other work with lv...
    }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `self` keyword to access static members. You also have a missing `$` in your variable name:

```
lv = st_ar[1];
```

needs to be:

```
$lv = self::st_ar[1];
```

Comment: I just saw my enormous error :D
I did not put the $ to the variable! What a shame